# ASP.NET MVC - Ajax call to open Index view in separate window

Tags: asp.net-mvc

**Task:** on click of a button, I need to open an `Index` view on a controller in a separate window.

Method with Ajax call:

```
function openHelpTopic(helpItemName, caller) {

    var formData = {
        //Some data
    };

    $.ajax({
        type: "Get",
        url: "/Help/details",
        data: formData
    }).done(function (results) {
        var helpURL = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + "/" + "Help/Index";
        window.open(helpURL, "Help");        
    });
}
```

`Index.cshtml`:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Help";
}
<h1>Help</h1>
<div id="helpDetails">
    @{Html.RenderPartial("_HelpDetails")}
</div>
```

Partial view:

```
@model CMS.Web.ViewModels.Help.HelpVM

<h3>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Caller)</h3>
<h3>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.SysName)</h3>
<h3>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserID)</h3>
<h3>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.HelpItemName)</h3>
```

Controller:

```
public class HelpController : Controller
{
    // GET: Help
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Details(HelpVM helpVM)
    {
        return PartialView(helpVM);
    }
}
```

The flow returns the partial view on details action, and fails at the next step to load the `Index` view.

Any advice on how to make it work?